# Line colors overlap when changed

Tags: qt, qml

I am working on an QML program in which I change the color and the border color of a polygon painted on a Canvas. I have 2 buttons that change the colors, ie. 1 button making the border color red and the other one blue.

My problem is that each time I change the color set, the border of the polygon seems "corrupted", such as the used border colors mixed with each other. The drawn polygon is being resized each time I resize the window. So when I resize, its being repainted I believe. The colors are getting fixed at that point.

My question is: is there a way to disable the overlapping or is there a way to manually force the redrawing of all Canvases in the project?

Ucolors.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9

/**
 * @brief   Holds the color parameters of the whole UI
 *
 */
Item
{
    property var canvas
    property var text
    property var spiderBckgrnd
    property var spiderLines
}
```

main.qml

```
Ucolors
{
    id: colDay

    canvas: "#eaedf1"
    text: "#0e0e12"
    spiderBckgrnd: "#f7fbff"
    spiderLines: "#C8CBD0"
}

Ucolors
{
    id: colNight

    canvas: "#22212c"
    text: "#ffffff"
    spiderBckgrnd: "#0e0e12"
    spiderLines: "#3C3C3F"
}

property var colGlob: colDay

Button
{
    id: btn1
    anchors.left: parent.left
    text: "button1"

    onClicked:
    {
        colGlob = colNight;
    }
}

Button
{
    id: btn2
    anchors.left: btn1.right
    text: "button2"

    onClicked:
    {
        colGlob = colDay;
    }
}
```

Then in the code colors are set like this: `some_property: colGlob.spiderLines`

Comment: Your code doesn't run.

Comment: This is not the whole code, but just the part where I explain how is it done. I did not want to paste everything not to blur the problem.

Comment: You should always post the minimum amount of code that reproduces the problem. That means reducing the code and ensuring that it runs so that others can actually help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not explicitely call `clearRect()` on the context object of your `Canvas`, any drawing is painted on the existing content.

Since you're drawing a polygon, some antialiasing pixels are added on the edges to get smooth lines. Those pixels are semi-transparent, so when you draw the same polygon over the existing one with another color, color blending occurs on the edges; hence the "corrupted" appearance.

When you change the height or width of the canvas, the context is implicitely cleared, so the "corrupted" edge disappears.

An easy fix is to call `clearRect` in the `onPaint` handler of your `Canvas`.

```
Canvas
{
    id: canvas
    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext("2d")

        // Clear the canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

        // Draw anything you want
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is a small example that reproduces your problem, and show how it is fixed by calling clearRect

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 200

    property string color: "red"
    onColorChanged: {
        canvas.requestPaint()
    }

    ColumnLayout
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 20
        spacing: 20
        RowLayout
        {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            Repeater
            {
                model: ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
                Button
                {
                    text: modelData
                    highlighted: root.color == modelData
                    onClicked: {
                        root.color = modelData
                    }
                }
            }
            CheckBox
            {
                id: clearBeforeRepaintCb
                text: "Clear before paint"
            }
        }

        Canvas
        {
            id: canvas
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d")
                if(clearBeforeRepaintCb.checked)
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
                ctx.strokeStyle = root.color
                ctx.lineWidth = 10
                ctx.beginPath()
                ctx.moveTo(10, height/2)
                ctx.lineTo(width-10, height/2+3)
                ctx.stroke()
            }
        }
    }
}
```